# how to identify unsaved value from database using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have to identify unsaved value from mysql table using php and mysql, for example i using table named as **numtab** and i have already stored some numbers **1, 3, 4, 7, 23, 12, 45** in **numb** column.

now i have **generated one new number randomly**(for example 23) and i have to check this number with already stored numbers,

if 23 is exist in the table mean i have to generate another one new number and have to check once again with stored values, this process have to continue till finding unsaved number.

if generated value is not exist in table mean can stop the process and can store this number in table.

here below the format i am currently using

```
$numb=23;
$qryb="select * from numtab where numb='$numb'";
$results=mysql_query($qryb)or die("ERROR!!");
if(mysql_num_rows($results) == 1)
{
    $numb=rand(1,100);
    mysql_query("insert query");   
}
```

the problem is above the code is validation once only, its not verifying second time. i think if using **for** or **while loop** mean can solve this problem, but i dont know how to do looping, so help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Why can you not use a stored procedure to generate these numbers and return the final number generated?

Comment: @scragar - i am new to php mysql, can you tel me clearly to do stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can use in clause like this :

```
$qryb="select * from numtab where numb in('$numb')";
$results=mysql_query($qryb)or die("ERROR!!");
$count = mysql_num_rows($results);


if ($count > 0) {
      echo "number exist in db";
} else {
     echo "number does not exist in db";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a while() loop to check if the numbers exist in your database. You could also retrieve all numbers from the database, store them in an array and check if the generated number exists within that array.

The first option would be something like this:

```
do {
  $numb=rand(1,100);
  $qryb="select * from numtab where numb='$numb'";
  $results = mysql_query($qryb) or die("ERROR!!");
} while(mysql_num_rows($results) >= 1)
mysql_query("insert query");
```

The second option would be something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(numb) as numb FROM numtab");

// set array
$array = array();

// look through query
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
  // add each row returned into an array
  $array[] = $row['numb'];
}

do 
{
  $numb = rand(1,100);
}
while(!in_array ( $numb , $array) ;
mysql_query("insert query");
```

Comment: if you don't mine can you tel me clearly to this process (using array).

Comment: Would be faster to store the values in your array as keys, then use isset, PHP is optimised for looking up keys, but doesn't optimise looking up values.